# App returning [] and [[[]]]] multiple times instead of numbers

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am using firebase to store a users location into the database, and I am getting returned this, I am not sure if it is an error or just something was interpreted wrong:

```
[]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\"]\\\"]\"]"]
```

This above but like 10x longer

Full Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import Firebase
import CoreLocationUI

struct MapView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    @State var address = ""
    @State var addresses:[String] = []
    
    @State var realLat:[String] = []
    @State var realLong:[String] = []
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(0..<realLat.count, id: \.self) {i in Text(realLat[i]) }
                    
                List(0..<realLong.count, id: \.self) {i in Text(realLong[i]) }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                downloadLatServerData()
                downloadLongServerData()
            })
        }
    }
    
    func downloadLatServerData() {
        //address = "Tokyo"  // <--- here for testing
        //addresses.append(address) // <--- here for testing
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("UserInfo").addSnapshotListener {(snap, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("\(String(describing: err))")
                return
            }
            for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                let documentId = i.document.documentID
                if let latCoordinate = i.document.get("lat") as? String {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        realLat.append(latCoordinate)
                        print("\(realLat)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func downloadLongServerData() {
        //address = "Tokyo"  // <--- here for testing
        //addresses.append(address) // <--- here for testing
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("UserInfo").addSnapshotListener {(snap, err) in
            if err != nil{
                print("\(String(describing: err))")
                return
            }
            for i in snap!.documentChanges {
                let documentId = i.document.documentID
                if let longCoordniate = i.document.get("long") as? String {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        realLong.append(longCoordniate)
                        print("\(realLong)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Sample Numbers:

Lat: -9128653.12
Long: -917532

Did those numbers 4 times, for 4 different users.

Comment: What does your actual data in firebase look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

use `realLat.append(latCoordinate)` **not** `realLat.append("\(realLat)")`

and similarly for `realLong`.

use `realLong.append(longCoordniate)` **not** `realLong.append("\(realLong)")`

Comment: It worked now thank you! - Put in the edited code into the original code snippet